# Eclipse VM Arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6, jvm-arguments

I am trying to run a sample web application by importing a pre-built project but I stuck with some error where CONTEXT_ROOT is not properly initialized so I went adding the value -DCONTEXT_ROOT="C:/...." in the VM arguments, and it worked.

But the same project works fine with my other colleague's machine even without adding this in VM argument.

We both are using the same IDE(eclipse) and same server but trying to identify what might be missing in my Workspace.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you run a web project in Eclipse, the project name will be the default context root. For example, for a project named “abc”, the context root will be

```
http://localhost:8080/abc
```

Also you should check the context root defined in: (right click on) project => properties => web project settings

Comment: Sorry. My Question is different.

When I ran the web application in eclipse, it throws some error like "Property file is missing or not found!", 

Then I realized the IDE is not able to identify the "CONTEXT_ROOT" of the app. So I added the exact path of the project (C:/Users/ADAM/ABC) as the context root in project's VM arguments, and then it worked as expected.

So my question is my Workspace needed a VM argument to be specified but not my other team members. How do I identify what is missing in my Workspace so that even when I run without VM arguments it should work.